# How to bypass authorization procedure only if the web API called within any other web API belongs to same domain - .Net-core 3.1 + Identity-server

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I want to access one of my web API endpoints within another web API. But need to skip authorization procedure only for this situation. It means i want to access mentioned endpoint without the access_token. But to access it by any client app (Mobile, Web) the access_token should be required. Is it possible?.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
{
    try
    {
        // some code
        return Ok(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need an API gateway project which contain authorization and your clients access this porject. then you can hide another projects behind the API gateway. with this scenario your webapi doen't need any authorization and they can call each other without authorization.

for more information about this approach see this:

[Api gateway pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

Comment: In my case i have an API, which accessed by a mobile client. And i want the same API to be accessed within another API, but need to bypass authorization only for this case. Can i do that?

Comment: in another hand, you can use client_credential grant type to generate an access_token for second API. when you are calling first API from second API, send your access_token which obtain with client_credential gran type. with this senario you don't need bypass authorization